# Set Option in MakeFile to send object files to specific Folder

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I made a test makefile using an online tutorial. It works, but I also want to have all of my .o files go to a specific sub-folder. Is there a way to do this using a makefile?  Here is what I have so far.

```
CC=gcc # specifies the compiler to use.

CFLAGS=-I. # specifies to look in the current directory.

DEPS = path_tools.h # DEPS stores each .h file to be added.

OBJ = checkpath.o path_tools.o # OBJ stores each object file to compile.

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)

        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

checkpath.exe: $(OBJ)

        gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

Comment: Do you understand what the makefile you current have does? And how it does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For GNU make you can use this Makefile.

```
    ODIR:=obj
    CC:=gcc
    CFLAGS:=-I.
    DEPS:=path_tools.h
    OBJ_:= checkpath.o path_tools.o
    OBJ:=$(addprefix $(ODIR)/, $(OBJ_))
    PROG=checkpath.exe
    all:$(PROG)
    $(OBJ): $(DEPS)
    $(ODIR)/%.o: %.c 
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
    $(PROG): $(OBJ)
        $(CC)  -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
    clean:
        rm -f $(OBJ)  $(PROG)
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't get this to work yet: matt@matt-VirtualBox:~/code$ make -f makefile_Example_new
make: *** No rule to make target 'path_tools.h', needed by 'obj/checkpath.o'.  Stop.

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. I had the wrong sub-folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the path of your folder to makefile to create and put the results in. 
To pass parameter to makefile:

make DPATH=your-path

To use in makefile:

$(DPATH)

Create this path and add it to head of your *.o files as a path.